# Is there any easier way to append text to an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I'm trying to compose a dynamic URL, is there any easier way to append the string besides doing it this way? This seems to inefficient.

```
NSString *folder1 = @"sonic";
NSString *folder2 = @"usr";
NSString *url = @"http://www.mydomain.com";

url = [url stringByAppendingFormat:@"/"];
url = [url stringByAppendingFormat:folder2];
url = [url stringByAppendingFormat:@"/"];
url = [url stringByAppendingFormat:folder1];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mydomain.com/%@/%@", folder2, folder1];
```